# Regex...non capturing group still capturing - javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Probably due to a misunderstanding of my own, but would like to confirm..

`var match = '4 bedroom house'.match( /(?:\d+ bedroom)(.*)/i);`

As I understand it `?:` should mean that while the group is used for matching, it shoudn't be returned in the results?

However when I console log `match` I get:

`["4 bedroom house", " house", index: 0, input: "4 bedroom house"]`

I am not interested in match[0] how can I exclude it?

Comment: `match[0]` is the entire string that is matched by the regular expression

Answer (score 0):

`(?:..)` called non-capturing group which does the matching operation only. `match` function in-turn return all the matched characters. In-order to return only the captured characters, you need to call `exec` function.

```
> /(?:\d+ bedroom)(.*)/i.exec('4 bedroom house')[1]
' house'
> /(?:\d+ bedroom\b)\s*(.*)/i.exec('4 bedroom house')[1]
'house'
```

`[1]` at the last helps to print all the characters which are captured by the group index 1.

Answer (score 0):

[match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) works the same as [exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) when the *g* flag is omitted. The first value in the matches array is the complete match so I don't think you can omit the first array value when using match or exec.

workaround to omit first value:

```
var match = ('4 bedroom house'.match( /(?:\d+ bedroom)(.*)/i)||[]).slice(1); // [" house"]
```